# Webpack 5 : how to import assets as ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Webpack 5.20.1, with [Asset Modules feature](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/).

When I import my assets, I got an "undefined" instead of the URL of the expected resource.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|xml|json)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

**MyFile.ts**

```js
import * as Phaser from 'phaser';

import sky from '../assets/sky.png';

export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

  public preload() {
    console.log("##### sky", sky); // got undefined
    this.load.image('sky', sky);
  }

}
```

I thought this use was legit.

Exploring transpiled bundle, I find an use of the path to `default`, when then asset is use. But no `default` in the export when the asset is build as module :

**app.bundle.js** (when using the asset)

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({ value: true }));
exports.GameScene = void 0;
var Phaser = __webpack_require__(/*! phaser */ "./node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser.js");
var sky_png_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! ../assets/sky.png */ "./src/assets/sky.png");
var GameScene = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(GameScene , _super);
    function GameScene () {
        var _this = _super.call(this, sceneConfig) || this;
        _this.score = 0;
        return _this;
    }
    GargoylesScene.prototype.preload = function () {
        console.log("##### sky", sky_png_1.default); // There is 'default' keyword
        this.load.image('sky', sky_png_1.default); // There is 'default' keyword
    };

    return GameScene;
}(Phaser.Scene));
exports.GameScene = GameScene;
```

**app.bundle.js** (when defined asset as module)

```
/***/ "./src/assets/sky.png":
/*!****************************!*\
  !*** ./src/assets/sky.png ***!
  \****************************/
/***/ ((module, __unused_webpack_exports, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + "assets/47a86b192804f1490bee.png"; // There is NO 'default' keyword

/***/ }),
```

Where did I go wrong ?

**How can I configure webpack to load my resources as expected?**

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround : use the `*` when importing assets.

**MyFile.ts**

```js
import * as Phaser from 'phaser';

import * as sky from '../assets/sky.png'; // use `* as`

export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

  public preload() {
    console.log("##### sky", sky); // got undefined
    this.load.image('sky', sky);
  }

}
```

will be transpiled into

**app.bundle.js** (when using the asset)

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({ value: true }));
exports.GameScene = void 0;
var Phaser = __webpack_require__(/*! phaser */ "./node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser.js");
var sky = __webpack_require__(/*! ../assets/sky.png */ "./src/assets/sky.png");
var GameScene = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(GameScene , _super);
    function GameScene () {
        var _this = _super.call(this, sceneConfig) || this;
        _this.score = 0;
        return _this;
    }
    GargoylesScene.prototype.preload = function () {
        console.log("##### sky", sky);
        this.load.image('sky', sky);
    };
    
    return GameScene;
}(Phaser.Scene));
exports.GameScene = GameScene;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been a year ago, but in case anyone else is having this problem.

To solve this, you have to change how TS will compile imports by setting [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) to true. From the docs, you can also get by with just setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to true, since `esModuleInterop` turns that to true under the hood.

Sample

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./frontend/src",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["./frontend/src", "./tests"]
}
```